# Display Popup if Time Zone is Changed in Android device

Tags: android, timezone

I want to display notification or pop-up message that "Your TimeZone is Changed" in my android app if **System timezone** is Changed.please give me any suggesion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a BroadcastReceiver with the following intent-filter.

```
<receiver android:name=".TimezoneReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED " />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then inside the TimezoneReceiver Class :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    //Show Popup
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,Let me try

Comment: android:enabled="true" ,what is the use of giving this @Shivam Verma

Comment: Is it possible to create pop-up dialog inside  "onReceive()" method?,some of web sources are saying that u cant create ,and you have to start activity from "onReceive()",and in activity you have to display popup,Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you can't create a popup directly. You'll need an activity but you can make an activity look like dialog and open that instead.